# Specify directory for external C++ library +NDK +Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, box2d

I'm new to this NDK build and I'm having trouble with running this Buildbox project in android studio.

After linking C++ to Gradle using ndk-build and syncing, it is giving this error.

```
Android NDK: C:\AndroidApps\app\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'box2D' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
```

I can see reference for cocos2dx in the java and resources subfolders.

I'm not sure if I have to download box2D,core,cocos2dx library .

What changes do I have to make to the android.mk file so that the errors are gone?

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := player_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libplayer

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp 

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  core_static cocos2dx_static box2d_static

GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE := true

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt)

$(call import-module, box2D)
$(call import-module, core)
$(call import-module, cocos2dx)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error too. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

NDK does not download imported modules for you. I am not sure if there are plans to add such feature (parallel to XCode pods) in the future.

You will find detailed description of **import-module** [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/675fe49445e65ba44d91f4d85ed9b4d5b5ff6745/docs/IMPORT-MODULE.TXT), but basically you can set **`NDK_MODULE_PATH`** in your **Application.mk** file, with `;` separators on Windows, but using straight `/` in paths instead of Windows native backsashes, e.g. `C:/ext`), and then

```
$(call import-module, box2D)
```

will be equivalent to

```
include C:/ext/box2D/Android.mk
```